# What is the function of "siendo" in the sentence "No creo que ella se viera bien siendo sarcástica."?

Tags: gerundio

What is the function of "siendo" in the sentence 
"No creo que ella se viera bien siendo sarcástica."?

Answer (score 2):

The word "siendo" in this sentence is what is know  as a *gerundio predicativo*.

*Participios predicativos* are, shortly speaking, a special type of adjuncts that specify some characteristic associated to whatever they reference. They are very similar in form to a *complemento circunstancial de modo*, as described by Gustavson, but present some conceptual differences as well as the telltale sign of requiring agreement in number and gender with the object they apply to. Compare

> Llegó tarde -> complemento circunstancial, doesn't require agreement.
>
> Llegó contenta -> complemento predicativo, requires agreement.

The NGLE gives the following example as a *complemento predicativo*:

> Las mujeres lucimos más bonitas embarazadas.

And argues how "embarazadas" is a *complemento predicativo* to "lucimos".

Gerunds can often take on the role of being part of a *complemento predicativo* when they specify, among other things, a state or circumstance. This makes them look like a *complemento circunstancial*, even though they fit the definition of a *complemento predicativo* better:

[image]

In your sentence, the *gerundio predicativo* "siendo", together with its *atributo* "sarcástica", expresses a circumstance in which the person doesn't look good. Because it specifies a characteristic about the subject ("ella es sarcástica"), it's a *complemento predicativo*. This sentence is similar in form to the first example from the NGLE:

> Las mujeres | lucimos | más bonitas | embarazadas.
>
> (No creo que) Ella | se viera | bien | siendo sarcástica.

Therefore, whatever is said form the first sentence applies more or less to the second:

> Cuando están embarazadas, las mujeres lucen más bonitas.
>
> Cuando es sarcástica, ella no se ve bien.

Both "lucir" and "verse" are semi-copulative verbs, which often take *complementos predicativos* the same way copulative verbs take *atributos*.

Comment: +1 Es correcto tu análisis, no así el mío.

Answer (score 1):

The present participial phrase (or clause) "siendo sarcástica" in the sentence:

*No creo que ella se viera bien siendo sarcástica*.

can be parsed as an adverbial adjunct of manner (complemento circunstancial de modo) within the noun clause "que ella se viera bien siendo sarcástica". Within the non-finite verb phrase, "siendo" is the head and "sarcástica" is a subject complement (predicativo subjetivo).

The main clause is "No creo", and what follows is a noun clause functioning as direct object (*No creo ESO / No LO creo*).

If we convert the subordinate into an independent clause, we have:

- Ella no se vio bien siendo sarcástica (Ella no se vio bien **de ese modo**.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple non-grammatical answer, the English version of that sentence could be translated as "I don't think she looks good being sarcastic", or "I don't think being sarcastic is a good look for her". So the function of siendo, "being", is assigning the action of sarcastic behavior to her.